# Is it possible to use vectorized Plot Legend?

Tags: plotting, legending, vector

I upload data using the following code

```
data = Import["L" <> # <> ".dat"] &/@{"10", "102", 
"103", "104"};
```

My function is

```
W[L_, r_] := 1 + 3 L + 2 L^2 - 6 r*L - 6 L (r*L) + 6 (r*L)^2;

Tu[L_, r_, d_, koff_, u_, W_] := ((u/d^2)* W[L, r]+6 u (L - 1)) + koff ((u/d^2) W[L, r]+6L*u)
```

I try to plot my function and would like to use the same trick for Plot Legend as I used for uploading data

```
LVals = {10, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4};
Show[LogLogPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[Tu[n, 0.5, d, 10^3, 10^5, W], {n, LVals}], {d, 0.01, 
   10^7}, AxesLabel -> {"d", "T"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "T vs d", PlotLegends -> 
   "L ="<> # &/@LVals, ListLogLogPlot[data], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Black}]
```

But it gives the following message:

> "Options expected (instead of !(((PlotLegends -> \"L = \" <> #1 &)\
>   ) /@ LVals)) beyond position 2 in LogLogPlot"

The following code works

```
Show[LogLogPlot[Evaluate@Table[Tu[n, 0.5, d, 10^3, 10^5, W], {n, LVals}],{d,0.01, 10^7}, 
AxesLabel -> {"d", "T"}, PlotLabel -> "T vs d", PlotLegends ->LVals], ListLogLogPlot[data], 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Black}]
```

and gets the legend as

> 10    100     1000    10000

But I want the legend as

> L=10 L=100 L=1000 L=10000

How should I do this?

p.s. Why do I also obtain the message:

> OptionValue::nodef: "Unknown option !(\"PlotStyle\") for Graphics."

Comment: 1a) `a -> b[#]& /@ c` is `(a -> b[#])& /@ c` instead of `a -> (b[#]& /@ c)`

Comment: 1b) `Plot` holds its arguments, so the `Map` doesn't even evaluate (otherwise you'd get a list of `PlotLegend -> ...` and be wondering why you legend shows up wrong.)

Comment: 2) `PlotStyle` is only an option for `Plot`, but `Graphics` (which is what `Show` is working with) doesn't know anything about it. (Unlike `PlotRange` and `PlotLabel`, which are general graphics options.)

Comment: @BrettChampion , how should I specify then that I want the same color for the same `L` for data and plotting curve?

Comment: Use the same setting for `PlotStyle` in both `LogLogPlot` and `ListLogLogPlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListLogLogPlot[data]` does not impact the issue here, so I omit it for convenience.  Then,

```
Show[LogLogPlot[
   Evaluate@Table[Tu[n, 0.5, d, 10^3, 10^5, W], {n, LVals}], {d, 0.01, 10^7},
   AxesLabel -> {"d", "T"}, PlotLabel -> "T vs d", 
   PlotLegends -> {"L = " <> ToString[#] & /@ LVals}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Black}]]
```

gives the desired plot.  The changes are to move `PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Black}` inside `LogLogPlot`, as recommended by [Brett Champion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/69/brett-champion), and to rewrite `PlotLegends`.

[image]

Comment: but why does `#` work without `ToString` in the case of importing data and doesn't in the case of **PlotLegends**?

Comment: @Maria When you used `Import["L" <> # <> ".dat"] &/@{"10", "102", "103", "104"}`, your list already was made up of strings, like `"10"`.  You could, of course, use a list of strings with ``PlotLegends`, if you wish.  However, you could not use that same list in your `Table`.